# What ML model is best suited for an intelligent search assistant?

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, ai, gpt

I'm working on my thesis project, and want to make an intelligent search assistant that understands context and, of course, processes and repsonds in natural languaje. The data I want to train this model on is from the Virtual Observatory and a [python library](https://pyvo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can be used to retrieve data from it.

I thought on Open AI's GPT-3 API, but the knowledge to which it has access to is outdated. The I thought about IBM's Wattson Discovery, but I feel that using their solution would limit the response type or the training process very much.

What ML model(s) would work better in my case? Or what software/solution would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

You could use OpenAI's API, GPT3.5 and use those to build a retrieval augmented generation model (RAG) to search a vector store of contexts of your choosing. You can do this using a couple of different python packages such as [LLamaIndex](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/getting_started/concepts.html) or [Langchain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/cookbook/retrieval). Of course, this only makes sense if you intend to have it search information that you have in text documents. This course from [DeepLearning.ai](https://www.deeplearning.ai/short-courses/langchain-chat-with-your-data/), should also get you started with RAG and LLMs. You could also choose to use Llama2 if you prefer to not use OpenAI models or if your data is proprietary.

Comment: Thanks! I'll study about RAG and see if I can make a decent search assistant, but it will depend on how I can access the data. I'll come back later on to update the question.